# make iframe content stay inside div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make a tablet app in html.
I want to have a topbar with some buttons and an area below with a iframe where i can load content in a protected area.

the base of the page is build as this:

```
<div id="topMenu"></div>
<div id="webdiv">
  <iframe id="frame"/>
</div>
```

and my css is:

```
#topMenu{
    height: 32pt;
}

#webdiv{
    height: calc(100% - 32pt);
    width: 100%;
    overflow: ??;
}

#frame{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    overflow: ??;
}
```

so my problem is that i don't know what to put in the overflow attributes (or what ever i need to do).
I want it so that the content of the iframe can be large, but at no point would move the topbar. meaning that the iframe has a scrollbar of some sort.
but no matter what i try it either lock everything so no scrolling, or the content is one big so that the topbar is moved outside the window when scrolling down.

any idea what i have done wrong?
thanks...

Comment: make overflow-y:scroll; on #webdiv and overflow:none on iframe..

Comment: what do you need with overflow:none? i haven't seen the value none no the attribute overflow before!!

Comment: i meant hidden.. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that kinda works. i simply make the iframe the size that it needs, and then the topbar has z-index=2 with a fixed position meaning it is on top of the other. but the content is then scrolled up behind the topbar, resulting that if for some reason, the web page in the iframe has a topbar itself, it will be hidden when it is scrolled. but thats not a problem right now.
thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some styles to the `html` and `body` tags

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NwQmp/2/)

Comment: hmm okay. so i followed you're demo and didn't work. i then embedded you're demo directly and still didn't work. didn't even work when i open the Demo in safari on my ipad. so my conclusion. iFrames dosen't work properly on ipad.

Comment: well if you look at the demo on your iPad of course it wont work. jsFiddle uses iFrames to render results and the demo uses another iframe. iOS wont obey fixed elements inside of an iframe

Comment: is there any other way of embedding some content into my app like this. i might accept it not being in a protected area.
btw., i'm using phonegap to port it to a "real" app, if it changes anything?.

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to load in the iframe? If you don't need to load full html pages, you could use ajax to load partial html and insert into scrollable `div`

Comment: it is a full html page that need to be loaded. in theory it could be any webpage, with javascript and css, so i might get in trouble with javascript object with the same name, and properly other stuff aswell.?
is it posible to make a sandbox kinda area of some sort?